# Reading characters from a line of a file

Tags: c++

The first line of my file must be exactly a two digit number which I read into firstline[2]. I use sscanf to read the data from that buffer and store it into an int to represent the number of lines (not including the first one) in the file. If there is a third character I must exit with an error code.

I've tried introducing a new char buffer thirdchar[1] and comparing it to a new line (10 or '\n'). If thirdchar does not equal newline then it should exit with an error code. Later in my program I use sscanf to read firstline and store that number into an int called numberoflines. When I intriduce thirdchar, it appends an extra two zeros to numberoflines to the end of what was in firstline.

```
//If the first line was "20"
int numberoflines;
char firstline[2];
file.get(firstline[0]);//should be '2'
file.get(firstline[1]);//should be '0'

char thridchar[1];
file.get(thirdchar[0]);//should be '\n'

if (thirdchar !=10){exit();}//10 is the value gdb spits out to represent '\n'

sscanf(firstline, "%d", &numberoflines);//numberoflines should be 20
```

I debugged this and firstline and thirdchar are the expected values, but numberoflines becomes 2000! I've removed the code related to thirdchar and it works fine, but doesnt meet the requirement of it being a 2 digit number. Am I misunderstanding what sscanf does? Is there a better way to implement this? Thanks.

---------------UPDATE------------------

So I've updated my code to use std::string and std::getline:

```
std::string firstline;
std::getline(file, firstline);
```

And I get the following error when trying to print the value of firstline

```
$1 = Python Exception <class 'gdb.error'> There is no member named _M_dataplus.:
```

Comment: Why don't you use [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read the line into a [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), then [convert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) it to an integer? Afterwards you can check the integer value to make sure it's valid.

Comment: As for your current code, don't forget that `char` strings are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. That *null-terminated* bit is quite important.

Answer (score 1):

`sscanf` requires the input string to be [null-terminated](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ntcs/). You are not passing it a null-terminated string so it's not behaving as expected.

As suggested, you would be better placed reading in the string using [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and converting the `std::string` into an integer.

Further reading [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) if using C++11 onwards, or [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) otherwise.

Comment: So when trying to declare first line as ```std:string firstline;``` i get this error: ```Python Exception <class 'gdb.error'> There is no member named _M_dataplus.:```

Comment: Have you verified that's not what's in the file you're reading?

Comment: If you mean am I sure what I am expecting to read is in the file, then yes I am sure.

Comment: @biscuitduke This will be a problem with your compiler/environment as opposed to the code. A quick google for the error message provides a list of people with the issue.